# Calling to an aggregation function using GET request

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

I'm trying to call my aggregation function from A `GET` request, but the response is EMPTY.

Can someone help me with this? Here is my code:

**The aggregation function:**

```
function t1(callback) {
  userScheme.aggregate([
 // Unwind the array
{ "$unwind": "$result"},

// Group on the "_id" and "name" and $sum "value"
{ "$group": {
   "_id": { 
       //"_id": "$_id",
       "game": "$result.game"
   }, 
   "time": { "$avg": "$result.time" } 
}},

// Put things into an array for "nice" processing
{ "$group": {
   "_id": "$_id",
   "values": { "$push": { 
       "game": "$_id.game",
       "time": "$time"
   }}
}}
 ] , callback) 
}
```

**My `GET` request:**

```
userRoutes.route('/getavg').get(function(req, res) {
    t1(function(err, user) {
        if (err)
                res.status(500).send("Internal error occurred.");
        else
                res.json(user);
    })
});
```

What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: 1) Remove all the stage from the aggregation pipeline and see what you are getting. 2) You are living with an old fashion manner(`callbacks`). Try to use something new using `async` `await`

Comment: When I have printed the response at the aggregation function, I got data, so I think that the issue is with my GET function

Comment: I can see nothing wrong with the above code.  You might checking at the wrong place or in the wrong file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is looking fine.

What I'd suggest you is to try and simplify your code.
Start by replacing the get function with something like

```
userRoutes.route('/getavg').get(function(req, res) {
  console.error("Testing");
  res.json({test: "works});
});
```

Then see if you get the response or if you see the console error.
If you still don't then it's a routing issue

Comment: Hello Nim, many thanks for your response! It was exactly routing issue.